# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy and no solution works

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having trouble in running my code. 
I did:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

It keep saying that: ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy

I followed this tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

and it keep getting me lots of import error not only for the sqlalchemy but also these:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required
```

all of above imports got me import errors.
I had check all similar questions on stack overflow and try all solutions but they did not work. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

here is error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5    /Users/Mia/Documents/workspace/Assignment3.2/run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mia/Documents/workspace/Assignment3.2/run.py", line 1, in <module>
from app import app
File "/Users/Mia/Documents/workspace/Assignment3.2/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ImportError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

I felt it's very strange when I check the version of python in my project directory, it's 2.7. But above shows it's 3.5. Will that causing problems?

Comment: do you have these installed? Do a `pip freeze` to see what you have installed.

Comment: @Connie I did pip freeze and here is the result: Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.12
Werkzeug==0.11.5

Comment: try changing `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` to `from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`. If you look at Miguel's github, his code has been updated to use the latter.

Comment: @Connie Thanks for your comment. I've try both but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running from the virtualenv.  Notice the path to the Python binary in the traceback: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5`, the system Python.

Activate the virtualenv, then run the program.

```
source ./flask/bin/activate
python run.py
```

Or, *follow the tutorial* and add the correct executable instruction to the top of the script, then execute the script directly (after marking it executable with `chmod +x ./run.py`).

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

```
./run.py
```